# Equivalent of Java Orika/Dozer/MapStruct Data mapper for PHP (Laravel/Eloquent)?

Tags: php, spring-mvc, dozer, orika, mapstruct

I'm wondering if there's an analogue of java's [Orika](http://orika-mapper.github.io/orika-docs/intro.html) data mapper for PHP/Laravel/etc?

I've looked around and seen Doctrine etc, but these seem to just be ORM's. What I need is to map/import from an old archaic (badly normalised database) into a new fresh laravel/eloquent database. I've had experience with Spring MVC and would commonly use Orika to map between old objects to and new.

Is there something similar for PHP?

To clarify, this is purely to ingest data from the old DB structure to new. Once we're happy with how the data looks in the new table structure, it will no longer be used.

As a last resort we could even resort to building an import tool in java, but would prefer a PHP solution because the other devs have experience there.